# iPad 2018 completely dead

Tags: ipad, hardware, crash, charging

I have a iPad 2018, which will not turn on anymore. I was just browsing on safari and suddenly the iPad crashed and will not turn on anymore. I tried the following:

- Charge the iPad (with different chargers)
- Tried doing a hard reset and power on
- Connected it to a iMac, iMac won't recognize the iPad.

In all of the cases the iPad will not turn on or show any sight of life.
How can I fix this?

**Edit**

Crash details: I was on Safari when the iPad crashed. The image froze and I couldn't do anything. After a while, the iPad turned off and never turned on again.

Comment: Try putting it into [DFU mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212787) and see if it will respond. If it doesn’t you might have to take it in for service.  Can you describe the “crash”. That might give some clues as to what happened exactly.

Comment: @Allan I tried DFU mode but the iPad doesn't show any sight of live. I also updated my question with some details on the crash.

Comment: Thats not a good crash.  I suspect the logic board is dead.  You need to take it in fir service.

Comment: @Allan Oké, is there something else I can do to fix the iPad?

Comment: There is no magic button sequence that will turn it on.  You’ve got to take it in for diagnostics/service.

Comment: Oke thank you for your help